# Mysql update: ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

Tags: mysql

My problem is the following:
I have a table `foo_table` with id column `ID` as `bigint (primary key)`, name column `NAME` as `varchar(80)` and code COLUMN code as `varchar(20)`. I have a unique constraint on the CODE column.

If I fill this table with only "number" strings in the code column, and then one day decide to add a row with a, surprise, "string" string in that code column, say putting "My Code", it works fine ! The error comes when I tried updating one of my previous records, one that has a CODE value being a number; in this case I get the famous error saying:

> ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'My Code'.

I'm not even touching that record ! I presume MySQL is trying to check the unique constraint and try to convert every value in the CODE column to double, but that's insane, and very unprofessional.

Anyone has a solution ? Like turning off string<->number conversion in MySQL ?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Ok I have the sample code, but while creating it I saw how to fix the problem, which is still a problem in MySQL as far as I'm concerned:

```
CREATE TABLE foo_table (
ID bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
NAME varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
CODE varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
UNIQUE KEY foo_table_uk (CODE)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 CHECKSUM=1 DELAY_KEY_WRITE=1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

insert into foo_table (id, name, code) values (1, 'one', '1');
insert into foo_table (id, name, code) values (2, 'two', '2');
insert into foo_table (id, name, code) values (3, 'three', 'three');

update foo_table set name='a-one', code='1' where code=1; <-- This update throws the error

update foo_table set name='a-one', code='1' where code='1'; <-- this update works fine
```

Comment: Please add the exact UPDATE statement, and the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE.